# Plex and Emby Servers not working

Tags: plex, mediaserver, emby

I just applied an update the other day and did a restart. Now, Plexmediaserver is not reachable, even from the desktop it is running on. Plex was working fine for over a year.
So, I thought I would see if Emby would work. Installed it, connected the libraries. Tried connecting some screens in my house to it. Nope, they say the server is not reachable. What happened? Why won't Ubuntu let me serve media in my own network anymore.
Plex is the snap, and Emby is the current .deb.
I am on 22.04.

Comment: Have you tried booting into the previous kernel to eliminate a kernel update as the issue?

Comment: Are the applications running? Are the applications listening for inbound connections?